# StackOverFlow exception when run lint build task?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lint

Here is the console output, I don't known why this happen.
Please help me...I run this in another place, the lint task run with no error. 
I can provide more log info if needed...help. help help help. help help help. help help

```
12:02:43.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
12:02:43.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:02:43.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
12:02:43.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':android-nova-main:lintDebug'.
12:02:43.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
12:02:43.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
12:02:43.508 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
12:02:43.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':android-nova-main:lintDebug'.
12:02:43.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
12:02:43.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
12:02:43.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
12:02:43.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
12:02:43.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
12:02:43.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
12:02:43.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
12:02:43.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
12:02:43.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
12:02:43.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
12:02:43.511 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
12:02:43.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
12:02:43.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
12:02:43.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
12:02:43.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
12:02:43.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
12:02:43.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
12:02:43.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
12:02:43.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
12:02:43.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
12:02:43.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
12:02:43.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
12:02:43.512 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding.readableName(ReferenceBinding.java:1635)
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ReferenceBinding.debugName(ReferenceBinding.java:903)
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodBinding.toString(MethodBinding.java:1262)
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.android.tools.lint.EcjParser$EcjResolvedMethod.getSignature(EcjParser.java:1797)
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.squirrel_explorer.eagleeye.lint.b.a.d.visitMethodInvocation(ProGuard:27)
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at lombok.ast.MethodInvocation.accept(MethodInvocation.java:114)
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at lombok.ast.MethodInvocation.accept(MethodInvocation.java:115)
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at lombok.ast.VariableDefinitionEntry.accept(VariableDefinitionEntry.java:105)
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at lombok.ast.VariableDefinition.accept(VariableDefinition.java:155)
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at lombok.ast.VariableDeclaration.accept(VariableDeclaration.java:103)
12:02:43.513 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at lombok.ast.Block.accept(Block.java:106)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at lombok.ast.MethodDeclaration.accept(MethodDeclaration.java:240)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at lombok.ast.NormalTypeBody.accept(NormalTypeBody.java:57)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at lombok.ast.ClassDeclaration.accept(ClassDeclaration.java:239)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.squirrel_explorer.eagleeye.lint.a.a.l.a(ProGuard:109)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.squirrel_explorer.eagleeye.lint.a.a.l.a(ProGuard:127)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.squirrel_explorer.eagleeye.lint.a.a.l.a(ProGuard:127)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.squirrel_explorer.eagleeye.lint.a.a.l.a(ProGuard:127)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.squirrel_explorer.eagleeye.lint.a.a.l.a(ProGuard:127)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.squirrel_explorer.eagleeye.lint.a.a.l.a(ProGuard:127)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.squirrel_explorer.eagleeye.lint.a.a.l.a(ProGuard:127)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.squirrel_explorer.eagleeye.lint.a.a.l.a(ProGuard:127)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.squirrel_explorer.eagleeye.lint.a.a.l.a(ProGuard:127)
12:02:43.514 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.squirrel_explorer.eagleeye.lint.a.a.l.a(ProGuard:127)
12:02:43.515 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.squirrel_explorer.eagleeye.lint.a.a.l.a(ProGuard:127)
```